# How to find average color of an image with ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick

How do I get the RGB values of the average color of an image, where each value is 0-255?  Such as "255,255,255"

I run this command to shrink the image down and it returns the 'rgba' value with the alpha channel and sometimes it gives text color names:

```
convert cat.png -resize 1x1\! -format "%[pixel:u]\n" info:
```

Output:

```
rgba(155,51,127,0.266087)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do the following to parse out just the comma-separated RGB values.  It also will not return text color names.

```
convert cat.png -resize 1x1\! \
    -format "%[fx:int(255*r+.5)],%[fx:int(255*g+.5)],%[fx:int(255*b+.5)]" info:-
```

Output format should look like:

```
155,51,127
```

This should work in ImageMagick 6.3.9.1+

Comment: It's easier to use the special output format `.txt` :-)

Comment: Building on this answer, I wanted to get the hex equivalent of the RGB triplet. I'm still noobish at command-line processing, so this might not be optimal, but hopefully it'll save someone time: `convert cat.png -scale 1x1\! -format '%[fx:int(255*r+.5)],%[fx:int(255*g+.5)],%[fx:int(255*b+.5)]' info:- | sed 's/,/\n/g' | xargs -L 1 printf "%x"`

Comment: Beware of ImageMagick's bad default handling of gamma issues; this may be especially apparent when scaling down to 1x1. A page with good info: http://www.ericbrasseur.org/gamma.html#ImageMagick

Answer (score 33):

There are two aspects to my answer:

1. Resize the original image to a 1-pixel-image. This pixel then will have the "average" color as ImageMagick's `convert` sees it.
2. Output the result as the special `.txt` format supported by `convert`. This text format enumerates all pixels of an image, giving first its coordinates (`$row,$column:`), then its RGB or CMYK values in different formats.

Here is a command which covers both aspects in one:

```
convert cat.png -resize 1x1 out.txt
cat out.txt
```

To get the output directly in the terminal window, you could use:

```
convert cat.png -resize 1x1 txt:-
```

Example output:

```
convert p4.png -resize 1x1 txt:-
  # ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 1,1,255,srgb
  0,0: (189,185,184)  #BDB9B8  srgb(189,185,184)
```

Comment: Much simpler and more detailed than the accepted answer.

Comment: To get the hex code in a single shot, try `convert p4.png -resize 1x1 txt:- | grep -Po "#[[:xdigit:]]{6}"`, and further pipe that to `tr A-F a-f` if you prefer lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

The C# way, using the NuGet Magick.Net package(s) and borrowing from the command line examples.

```
ImageMagick.IMagickColor<ushort> color;
using (ImageMagick.MagickImage image = new ImageMagick.MagickImage(file))
{
    // Get average color
    image.Resize(1, 1);
    color = image.GetPixels().First().ToColor();
}
```