# How do I increase the RGB value of a specific pixel with Image::Magic in Perl?

Tags: linux, perl, imagemagick, perl-module

I want get 1 pixel `(x=3, y=3)` and change its RGB values (R from `100` to `101`, G from `99` to `100`, B from `193` to `194`).

[image]

```
use strict;
use Image::Magick;
my $p = new Image::Magick;
   $p->Read( 'myfile.jpg' );

   my $pix = $p->GetPixel(
            width     => 1,
            height    => 1,
            x         => 3,
            y         => 3,
            map       => 'RGB',
            normalize => 0
        );

   # in $pix RGB value now?
```

How do I add `1` for all RGB components?

Can I split decimal RGB to 3 values (r,g,b) and increment separately,
and then merge three R,G,B values to one RGB? :) How do I do that?

```
   $pix = .... something code here...

   # make changes
   $p->SetPixel(
            x       => 3,
            y       => 3,
            channel => 'RGB',
            color   => [ $pix ]
        );
   $p->Write ('my_new_file.jpg');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a bit tricky to figure out, but here we go. I'll show you what I did to get to the result, not just how it works.

I'm using a small image that has your starting color `(100, 99, 193)`.

[image: starting image and color]

At the top of my program I will always have this code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;
use Image::Magick;
my $p = new Image::Magick;
$p->Read('33141038.jpg');

my @pixel = $p->GetPixel(
    x         => 1,
    y         => 1,
    map       => 'RGB',
    normalize => 1,
);
```

I checked [the documentation at imagemagick.org.](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php). It is linked in [Image::Magick on CPAN](https://metacpan.org/pod/Image::Magick). There I searched `GetPixel`. That yields two helpful things. One is the explanation, the other one [an example](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php#example) that shows that an array `@pixel` is returned, and not a scalar like you tried.

> Here we reduce the intensity of the red component at (1,1) by half:
>
> ```
> @pixels = $image->GetPixel(x=>1,y=>1);
> ```

Ok. Let's use that. I've already got the `@pixel` in my code above. Note that I also turned on the `normalize` option. You can leave that out as it's on by default.

```
p @pixel;

# [
#     [0] 0.392156862745098,
#     [1] 0.388235294117647,
#     [2] 0.756862745098039
# ]
```

So those are floats. After some googling I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25488429/1331451), which deals with something similar. It looks like a fraction of `255`. Let's multiply. We can modify things in `@pixel` by assigning to `$_` in the postfix `foreach`. That's neat.

```
$_ *= 255 foreach @pixel;
p @pixel;

# [
#     [0] 100,
#     [1] 99,
#     [2] 193
# ]
```

That's what we wanted. Easy enough. Let's add one each.

```
$_ = ( $_ * 255 ) + 1 foreach @pixel;
p @pixel;

# [
#     [0] 101,
#     [1] 100,
#     [2] 194
# ]
```

Still good. But how do we get that back in? The docs have something to say about `SetPixel` in the [Manipulate section](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php#manipulate).

> color=>array of float values
>   [...]
>   set a single pixel. By default normalized pixel values are expected.

So apparently we need to go back to the float. No problem.

```
$_ = ( ( $_ * 255 ) + 1 ) / 255 foreach  @pixel;
p @pixel;

# [
#     [0] 0.396078431372549,
#     [1] 0.392156862745098,
#     [2] 0.76078431372549
# ]
```

Nice. We can of course also make the math a bit shorter. The result is the same.

```
$_ = $_ + 1 / 255 foreach @pixel;
```

Now let's write it back to the image.

```
$p->SetPixel(
    x => 1,
    y => 1,
    color => \@pixel, # need the array ref here
);

$p->Write('my_new_file.jpg');
```

In the screenshot, I changed it to add `20` instead of `1` so it's more visible.

[image: New image with +20 including freehand circles]

After cleaning up the code looks like this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;
use Image::Magick;

my $p = new Image::Magick;
$p->Read('33141038.jpg');

my @pixel = $p->GetPixel(
    x => 1,
    y => 1,
);

# increase RGB by 1 each
$_ = $_ + 1 / 255 foerach @pixel;

$p->SetPixel(
    x     => 1,
    y     => 1,
    color => \@pixel,
);

$p->Write('my_new_file.jpg');
```

I've removed the `map` and `channel` arguments from `GetPixel` and `SetPixel` as `RGB` is the default. Same for the `normalize`.

Comment: Very exhaustive answer! Sorry for bad english.

Comment: @Anton Don't worry about the English. It's fine to understand. I fixed it a bit to improve the question. Don't see that as critique on your skills please. It's one of the things we do here: try to improve the overall quality of the content on SO. After all, it's a knowledge collection. :)