# Find average colour of each section of an image

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, scikit-image

I am looking for the best way to achieve the following using Python:

1. Import an image.
2. Add a grid of n sections (4 shown in this example below).
3. For each section find the dominant colour.

[image: sky]

**Desired output**

Output an array, list, dict or similar capturing these dominant colour values.

Maybe even a Matplotlib graph showing the colours (like pixel art).

**What have I tried?**

The image could be sliced using image slicer:

```
import image_slicer
image_slicer.slice('image_so_grid.png', 4)
```

I could then potentially use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25488338/how-to-find-average-color-of-an-image-with-imagemagick) to get the average colour but Im sure there are better ways to do this.

**What are the best ways to do this with Python?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111029/how-to-find-the-average-colour-of-an-image-in-python-with-opencv

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the average colour of an image in Python with OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111029/how-to-find-the-average-colour-of-an-image-in-python-with-opencv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for 4 sections, but you'll need to figure out how to make it work for 'n' sections:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('image.png')

def fourSectionAvgColor(image):
    rows, cols, ch = image.shape
    colsMid = int(cols/2)
    rowsMid = int(rows/2)

    numSections = 4
    section0 = image[0:rowsMid, 0:colsMid]
    section1 = image[0:rowsMid, colsMid:cols]
    section2 = image[rowsMid: rows, 0:colsMid]
    section3 = image[rowsMid:rows, colsMid:cols]
    sectionsList = [section0, section1, section2, section3]

    sectionAvgColorList = []
    for i in sectionsList:
        pixelSum = 0
        yRows, xCols, chs = i.shape
        pixelCount = yRows*xCols
        totRed = 0
        totBlue = 0
        totGreen = 0
        for x in range(xCols):
            for y in range(yRows):
                bgr = i[y,x]
                b = bgr[0]
                g = bgr[1]
                r = bgr[2]
                totBlue = totBlue+b
                totGreen = totGreen+g
                totRed = totRed+r

        avgBlue = int(totBlue/pixelCount)
        avgGreen = int(totGreen/pixelCount)
        avgRed = int(totRed/pixelCount)
        avgPixel = (avgBlue, avgGreen, avgRed)
        sectionAvgColorList.append(avgPixel)
    return sectionAvgColorList

print(fourSectionAvgColor(img))
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use scikit-image's [`view_as_blocks`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.util.html#skimage.util.view_as_blocks) together with [`numpy.mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.16.0/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html). You specify the block size instead of the number of blocks:

```py
import numpy as np
from skimage import data, util
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

astro = data.astronaut()
blocks = util.view_as_blocks(astro, (8, 8, 3))

print(astro.shape)
print(blocks.shape)

mean_color = np.mean(blocks, axis=(2, 3, 4))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(mean_color.astype(np.uint8))
```

Output:

```
(512, 512, 3)
(64, 64, 1, 8, 8, 3)
```

[image: blocked and averaged]

Don't forget the cast to uint8 because matplotlib and scikit-image expect floating point images to be in [0, 1], not [0, 255]. See the [scikit-image documentation on data types](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/data_types.html) for more info.